# Paginate in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**I am writing the below code to paginate record...**

```
$Categories = \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model::all()->paginate(15);
```

**Then I got a runtime error says:**

> Method paginate does not exist.

**Am I missing something ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot paginate that way, `all()` function gives you a Collection already.

You need to use `\App\Models\Skill\Category_Model::paginate(15)` to do that.